# Linux session cleaner script picks the session path from php.ini instead of php-fpm pool configuration

Tags: php, linux, bash, session, debian

For my task, I want the linux built-in session cleaner (located at /usr/lib/php/sessionclean) to use the session path defined in the php-fpm configuration as per the following directive: php_admin_value[session.save_path]

Currently the sessionclean script is only picking the default path i.e. /var/lib/php/sessions to detect & clean sessions.

This is the code of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# sessionclean - a script to cleanup stale PHP sessions
#
# Copyright 2013-2015 Ondřej Surý <ondrej@sury.org>
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of
# this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in
# the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to
# use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of
# the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so,
# subject to the following conditions:
#
# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
# copies or substantial portions of the Software.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS
# FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR
# COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER
# IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN
# CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

SAPIS="apache2:apache2 apache2filter:apache2 cgi:php@VERSION@ fpm:php-fpm@VERSION@ cli:php@VERSION@"

# Iterate through all web SAPIs
(
proc_names=""
for version in $(/usr/sbin/phpquery -V); do
    for sapi in ${SAPIS}; do
        conf_dir=${sapi%%:*}
        proc_name=${sapi##*:}
        if [ -e "/etc/php/${version}/${conf_dir}/php.ini" ] && [ -x "/usr/bin/php${version}" ]; then
            # Get all session variables once so we don't need to start PHP to get each config option
            session_config=$(PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/etc/php/${version}/${conf_dir}/conf.d/ "/usr/bin/php${version}" -c "/etc/php/${version}/${conf_dir}/php.ini" -d "error_reporting='~E_ALL'" -r 'foreach(ini_get_all("session") as $k => $v) echo "$k=".$v["local_value"]."\n";')
            save_handler=$(echo "$session_config" | sed -ne 's/^session\.save_handler=\(.*\)$/\1/p')
            save_path=$(echo "$session_config" | sed -ne 's/^session\.save_path=\(.*;\)\?\(.*\)$/\2/p')
            gc_maxlifetime=$(($(echo "$session_config" | sed -ne 's/^session\.gc_maxlifetime=\(.*\)$/\1/p')/60))
            
            if [ "$save_handler" = "files" ] && [ -d "$save_path" ]; then
                proc_names="$proc_names $(echo "$proc_name" | sed -e "s,@VERSION@,$version,")";
                printf "%s:%s\n" "$save_path" "$gc_maxlifetime"
            fi
        fi
    done
done
# first find all open session files and touch them (hope it's not massive amount of files)
for pid in $(pidof $proc_names); do
    find "/proc/$pid/fd" -ignore_readdir_race -lname "$save_path/sess_*" -exec touch -c {} \; 2>/dev/null
done ) | \
    sort -rn -t: -k2,2 | \
    sort -u -t: -k 1,1 | \
    while IFS=: read -r save_path gc_maxlifetime; do
        # find all files older then maxlifetime and delete them
        find -O3 "$save_path/" -ignore_readdir_race -depth -mindepth 1 -name 'sess_*' -type f -cmin "+$gc_maxlifetime" -delete
    done

exit 0
```

**Additional Information:**

When I run the command php -i | grep 'session.save_path'. It shows the following output:

session.save_path => /var/lib/php/sessions => /var/lib/php/sessions

Though on my application's php info page shows the session.save_path value that is defined in php-fpm configuration.

So to summarize, I want to ask is this possible for session.save_path variable to pick the value if define in php-fpm otherwise use the default i.e. /var/lib/php/sessions ?

Comment: `Copyright 2013-2015 Ondřej Surý <ondrej@sury.org>`

Comment: Hi Saad ... do you manage to find the solution for this? Cause we have a similar issue where we moved the default session location for each fpm domain config.